# How to calculate precision, recall and F-score with libSVM in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, libsvm, precision-recall

I want to calculate the `precision`, `recall` and `f-score` using **libsvm** in Python but I do not know how. I have found [this site](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/eval/index.html) but I have not understand how to call the function, if you can help me through example.

Answer (score 12):

You can take advantage of [`scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/), which is one of the best packages for machine learning in Python. Its SVM implementation uses `libsvm`and you can work out precision, recall and f-score as shown in the following snippet:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

# prepare dataset
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# svm classification
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C = 1.0).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

# performance
print "Classification report for %s" % clf
print
print metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_predicted)
print
print "Confusion matrix"
print metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predicted)
```

Which will produce an output similar to this:

```
Classification report for SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.7,
kernel=rbf, max_iter=-1, probability=False, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
verbose=False)

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       1.00      1.00      1.00         9
          1       0.90      0.69      0.78        13
          2       0.64      0.88      0.74         8

avg / total       0.86      0.83      0.84        30


Confusion matrix
[[9 0 0]
 [0 9 4]
 [0 1 7]]
```

Of course, you can use the [`libsvm tools`](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/eval/index.html) you have mentioned, however they are designed to work only with binary classification whereas `scikit`allows you to work with multiclass.

Comment: What dataset you are loading ? For instance if my dataset is in the text file how to use them ?

Comment: In the example I used a predefined dataset called iris that comes with `scikit-learn`. For a particular dataset you will need to convert your text data in numpy matrixes.