# How to find the Precision, Recall, Accuracy using SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, libsvm

[Duplicate calculating Precision, Recall and F Score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927964/how-to-calculate-precision-recall-and-f-score-with-libsvm-in-python/16964420#16964420)

I have a input file with text description and classified level (i.e.levelA and levelB). I want to write a SVM classifier that measure  precision, recall and accuracy. I looked at [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) 
and [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) but I want to know more step by step.

Any sample code or basic tutorial would be really nice. Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate precision, recall and F-score with libSVM in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927964/how-to-calculate-precision-recall-and-f-score-with-libsvm-in-python)

Comment: Here's an extension for `libsvm`: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/eval/index.html

Answer (score 10):

These performance measures are easy to obtain from the predicted labels and true labels, as a post-processing step:

1. Precision = TP / (TP+FP)
2. Recall = TP / (TP+FN)
3. Accuracy = (TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FP + FN)

With TP, FP, TN, FN being number of true positives, false positives, true negatives and false negatives, respectively.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but I already did some study some basics but I need more specific information step by step implementation process.

Comment: The steps are: train an SVM (make sure to tune it properly), predict the test set, compute performance measures based on predicted labels and true labels.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any tutorial or book with code snippets. I don't want exact whole code but for learning purpose it would be really useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Raid The code is trivial. It is just a matter of keeping four counters and then using the formulae that Marc provided. For each predicted label: if predicted label == true label and true label is positive, increment TP; if predicted label == true label and label is negative, increment TN; if predicted label is positive and true label is negative; increment FP; otherwise increment FN. Try this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2akd6uwtowc.