# Calculating Precision, Recall, Accuracy using SVM

Tags: matlab, svm

I have trained SVM in matlab and then I transferred my model to OpenCV to detect the rear of a car. Here is the code.

```
pos_mat = matfile('posfeat.mat');               % positive samples
neg_mat = matfile('negfeat.mat');               % negative samples

posRow  = pos_mat.bigmat;                        % get positve samples
negRow  = neg_mat.bigmatneg;                     % get negative samples

group = ones(135,1);                             % get labels
group(70:135) = -1;

t = 70;
for i =1:1:66
    posRow(t,:) = (negRow(i,:));
    t = t+1;
end
xdata = posRow;


SVMModel = fitcsvm(xdata,group);

beta = (SVMModel.Beta)';
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Now I want to calculate the Precision, Recall and Accuracy of SVM classifier. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590105/how-to-find-the-precision-recall-accuracy-using-svm) is really useful but it only provide concepts related to  Precision, Recall, Accuracy. Can someone help me to calculate Precision, Recall, Accuracy of SVM classifier. You can find posfeat and negfeat [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rpkzoh1lev0vham/AAB1yuPfXE4ASliDQGzQTqCga?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

According to

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

The evaluation functions included in this tool are:

```
precision
Precision = true_positive / (true_positive + false_positive)
recall
Recall = true_positive / (true_positive + false_negative)
fscore
F-score = 2 * Precision * Recall / (Precision + Recall)
bac
BAC (Balanced ACcuracy) = (Sensitivity + Specificity) / 2,
where Sensitivity = true_positive / (true_positive + false_negative)
and   Specificity = true_negative / (true_negative + false_positive)
auc
AUC (Area Under Curve) is the area under the ROC curve.
```

Note: This tool is designed only for binary-class C-SVM with labels {1,-1}. Multi-class, regression and probability estimation are not supported. 
Note: When using accuracy as the evaluation criterion, the cross validation accuracy may be different from that by standard LIBSVM. The reason is that LIBSVM internally group data in the same class, while this tool does not.